# How can I make a file named "\$*'PNP'*$\" using touch command

Tags: linux, shell

How can I make a file named  `"\$*'PNP'*$\"` using touch command?
what I did:

```
% touch '"\$*'PNP'*$\"'
% ls 
"\$*PNP*$\"
```

I need ' beside P

Comment: My bad. I corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to put the desired filename in a Try:

```
$ touch "\"\\\$*'PNP'*$\\\""
$ echo *PN*
"\$*'PNP'*$\"
```

If you run `ls`, be aware that it may put escapes in the file name:

```
$ ls
'"\$*'\''PNP'\''*$\"'
```

In the above `touch` command, escapes are required.  First, to put a double-quote inside a double-quoted string, it must be escaped as `\"`.  Second to put a backslash in a double-quoted string, it must also be escaped as `\\`.  Inside a double-quoted string, `'` does not need to be escaped.

## Alternative: single-quoted string

```
$ touch '"\$*'\''PNP'\''*$\"'
$ echo *PN*
"\$*'PNP'*$\"
```

The above has five strings:

1. `'"\$*'`
2. `\'`
3. `'PNP'`
4. `\'`
5. `'*$\"'`

Strings 1, 3, and 5 are single-quoted strings.  Strings 2 and 4 are unquoted but escaped single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it into single quotes:

```
touch '"\$*'PNP'*$\"'
```